# Is it possible to set a sophisticated price set for events, like in this example?

Tags: civievent, price-sets

I am trying to facilitate a event but price sets are bit complicated, just wondering if anyone can give a clue how to sort it out please?

The "Early bird" pricing structure:

```
Single person -£285 pp

Couples - £240 pp

Family with kids - £220 pp (kids free under 2; £100 2-4yrs; £150 4-11yrs; over 12 £220)

We will be asking for 50% deposit upfront to secure their place and the remainder 50% within one month
```

Complication I am facing to give option for 50% deposit. Is it possible to do in civicrm 4.6.12?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is possible with off the shelf CiviCRM. You should certainly have a play with the CiviDiscount extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount if you have not already installed it. But even then I think your requirements would mean a specific extension. As you know you can develop an extension yourself or get a CiviCRM partner or expert to develop one for/with you.

Comment: If you want to give an 'early bird' discount you can set the price 'start' and 'end' date so that the 'discount' price ends on a particular date.  Getting them to automatically pay a balance is another story, you could select all the registrants and email them a scheduled 'reminder'